# Angular. Отследить событие появления id в элемента

Tags: события, ng-repeat

Есть несколько ссылок которые генерируются в `ng-repeat` из модели.
Есть переменная `curentPage` при изменении которой в одной из ссылок(определяется соответствие индекса ссылки к значению `curentPage`) добавляется id. Над элементом который имеет этот id должна появляться стрелочка - вычисляем позицию ссылки с данным id и соответственно со смещением отображаем стрелочку над этой ссылкой. Как это реализовать? В примере ниже если вводить в инпут "1" первая ссылка получает `id=pagePressed`, если "2" с первой ссылки id исчезает и добавляется ко второй. Как отследить момент появления id ? Или другие варианты?

Вот пример, в консоли можно посмотреть как изменяется `id` от значения в `input`
P.S. На ссылки можно не жать) это с другого примера переделано

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GldIqGS0G1TlDaCradky?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос с помощью пользовательской директивы `hoverSpot` и метода `$observe`

Подключил библиотеку *jquery*, так как не понял как задать позицию.

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GldIqGS0G1TlDaCradky?p=preview)